# Common technique to load data for many entities on one page using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

JS:

```
$('.product').each(function(){
    $parent = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $parent.attr('url'),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data){       
            $parent.text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For each product I want to load some data, say the price. I know the `each` function is not suitable for this because `each` does not wait for the `async ajax` process to finish.

In my example only the last product was filled with data.

How can I load data for each product on document load? Is there a common technique for this situation? Should the request be made for all products at once or for one by another?

Comment: Depends on where you are populating the AJAX response. Can you post the 'AJAX config' as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:** In your code `$parent` is not declared locally and hence becomes a global variable. Because of this, the last iteration of `$('.product').each() { .. }` overwrites it to be the last `$('.product')` element in your DOM.

**Solution:** If you change `$parent = $(this);` to `var $parent = $(this);`, it will likely start working correctly.

Comment: AWW thanks that works great. So as far as I understand each triggers several independet requests that do not interfere each other.

Comment: Exactly. They get sent as totally independent asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array in javascript that holds all your products id, and then call $.ajax on an interval of that array, on the finish event of the first ajax call, check if there are any more products left in the array and trigger again the ajax call until the array is empty. This way you will get the products buffered without making the ajax calls in parallel.

Comment: You mean some kind of recursive function called with the next available array index?

Comment: Yes a recursive function that will fetch from server a subset of your products array, this way you avoid having a single big JSON object and you don't stress the server by making a request for each product.